# Use clipboard as vector R (windows)

Tags: r

I'm trying to read my clipboard in R as a vector. I have a large list of numbers I need in vector format and I tried copy and pasting values before, but R stops after 4000 numbers.

```
#   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8  <--example of what's on clipboard

vector<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
vector[5]
#[1] 5
```

why cant I apply the same thing to the "read Clipboard" function?

```
vector<-c(readClipboard())
vector
vector[5]
#[1]"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
#[1]NA
```

is there anyway to get rid of the quotes and use these values?

Comment: Did you notice that `readClipboard()` is returning a single string with everything in it? You might want `strsplit(readClipboard(),",")`, and perhaps use `as.numeric` or `as.integer` on the resulting vector.

Comment: You may find the `clipr` package helpful, esp `read_clip_tbl`. Oops - beaten to it.

Comment: @dash2 `read.table(file="clipboard")` is sufficient actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `clipr` package.

```
> # clipboard: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
> library(clipr)
> read_clip_tbl(sep=",", header=FALSE)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

This output is a dataframe, but now you just have to take its first row:

```
tbl <- read_clip_tbl(sep=",", header=FALSE)
unlist(tbl[1,])
```

This gives a named vector:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

If you don't want the names:

```
> unname(unlist(tbl[1,]))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

## EDIT

In fact you don't need `clipr`. You can do:

```
> read.table(file="clipboard", sep=",")
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 1):

My use-case is generally working between Excel and R, in which case @StéphaneLaurent's answer works. (And, in fact, I tend to use `read.table(file='clipboard',header=F)` (or `=F`) instead of `readClipboard()`, as it has worked well for me in almost all situations.

If your string is non-tabular, though, as in a literal comma-delimited string, you can split it using:

```
# clipboard: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
s <- strsplit(readClipboard(), ",")
str(s)
# List of 1
#  $ : chr [1:8] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

There are several data-massaging you may want/need to do, depending on your use, such as: `as.integer(s[[1]])`, `as.numeric(s[[1]])`, or `trimws(s)` (not useful here).

Notice that I have not *yet* un-`list`ed it. In the event that you have more than one line copied, such as a clipboard with:

```
1,2,3,4,5
11,12,13,14
```

then

```
s <- strsplit(readClipboard(), ",")
str(s)
# List of 2
#  $ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#  $ : chr [1:4] "11" "12" "13" "14"
str(lapply(s, as.integer))
# List of 2
#  $ : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ : int [1:4] 11 12 13 14
```

and you can either refer to each line within as (say) `s[[1]]` for 1-5, or you can (as suggested in other answers) `unlist(s)` to combine

```
unlist(lapply(s, as.integer))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14
as.integer(unlist(s))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14
```

If the number of entries is always the same (i.e., CSV), such as a single row

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

with

```
read.csv(file='clipboard', header=FALSE)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  1  2  3  4  5
```

And multilines such as

```
1,2,3,4,5
11,12,13,14,15
```

into

```
read.csv(file='clipboard', header=FALSE)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  1  2  3  4  5
# 2 11 12 13 14 15
```

etc. From here, it can be `unlist`ed, `as.matrix`ed, or whatever you want, though `unlist` will do it by-column instead of by-row.